# DISTINCT ON with aggregate function

Tags: postgresql, distinct-on

I want to get the project with the highest number of views for each user in Postgres. This is the code I have so far:

```
  SELECT DISTINCT ON (user_id)
    project, user_id, COUNT(view_id) views
  FROM
    table_name
  GROUP BY
    user_id
  ORDER BY
    user_id, views DESC, project
```

Comment: Please explain the problem you're experiencing and update the question.

Comment: And what is the question ?